# android extracted mode keyboard and android:digits

Tags: android, user-interface, keyboard

I have an `EditText` field restricted to numbers and `.,-` with `android:digits` and set `android:inputType` to `numberSigned|numberDecimal`

My problem is when I switch to landscape mode, the IME goes to extracted mode and it lost any comma I put (I'm testing French locale).

If I delete `androud:inputType`, everything works well but the keyboard is not set to numeric keypad.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Just found it's an Android SDK bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2626